# Which is a more efficient way to use the If Condition?

Tags: javascript

I am using the IF condition inside a for loop.
I have two way to do that :

**1. I can use IF-Continue**

```js
for(let i=0;i<10;i++){
if(i%2==0) {
//doing some stuff
continue
}
console.log(i)
}
```

**2. I can use IF-ELSE**

```js
for(let i=0;i<10;i++){
if(i%2==0){
  //doing some stuff
}else{
console.log(i)
}
}
```

**Which way would be more efficient?**

Comment: Unless you are working with really big collection of data it doesn't matter.

Comment: Also, it might depend on the JavaScript interpreter -- so you should always benchmark before asking such questions. They're usually equal

Comment: Why not do this to loop through even numbers: `for(let i = 0; i < 10; i = i + 2){`?

Comment: Performance-wise, they should be equivalent/negligible gain. However, I would prefer the second one, since it's more readable and therefore easier to maintain

Comment: @codemonkey cause you miss the else part

Comment: This is probably [performance rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference in how the code works or which one is quicker. `continue` is basically the same as putting everything below in `else`.

What I do is: If you are doing something similar, I would use `if/else`. If what you are doing is conceptually different I would use the `continue` example.

Answer (score 4):

In terms of efficiency both are equal as both the codes loop through all the values. if you really want to loop through only even numbers then you can do it this way

```
for(let i=0;i<10;i=i+2){
//do some stuff
}
```

Comment: But he wants  the else case too. so his second approach is Okay.

Comment: This is not in terms of efficiency, but the amount of code (if branch/else branch) executed. It's possible that be some bad javascript interpreter has some hidden overhead...

Answer (score -1):

Just having a  single if-else case the use of `continue` keyword is need less.

Please try to learn  the  usage  of continue keyword first.

In your both cases,  the loop will traverse every time so no need to have continue at all.

Answer (score -1):

First approach is more efficient. Because it will minimise the number of execution.

If you iterating through a million of numbers, the efficiency would be visible. Since you want to do some tasks in both cases, I prefer to go ahead with the first aproach.

However the the above mentioned code snippet has the complexity of `O(n)` in both cases.

Comment: *"First approach is more efficient."* Please share your benchmarks